# ava + ts-node converting .spec.ts files into .ts

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ava, ts-node

I am running ava with ts-node with the following config:

```
"ava": {
    "files": [
        "tests/**/*",
        "!test/exclude-files-in-this-directory",
        "!**/exclude-files-with-this-name.*"
    ],
    "failFast": true,
    "failWithoutAssertions": false,
    "extensions": [
        "spec.ts",
        "ts"
    ],
    "environmentVariables": {
        "NODE_ENV": "test"
    },
    "require": [
        "ts-node/register",
        "tsconfig-paths/register"
    ],
    "tap": false,
    "verbose": true
}
```

The problem is that `.spec.ts` files don't get recognized, as ts-node is doing some kind of conversion (I think) of the `.spec.ts` files into just `.ts`, which means that the extension with `spec.ts` is never matched.

Here's the output of the tests

```
  - graphql › stage-2 › workspace.ts › do later
  ✔ general › functions.ts › returns proper difference
```

The files are named `workspace.spec.ts` and `functions.spec.ts`

Is there anyway for ts-node to not drop the `spec` part?

Answer (score 0):

`ts-node` should only kick in when AVA requires the test file. I can't immediately spot why this isn't working. Are those `spec.ts` files inside the `tests` directory?

P.S. `NODE_ENV` already defaults to `test`, and you don't need to disable `tap` either.

Comment: yep, they're inside the proper directories. Otherwise they wouldn't get called.